# GSOAP: Automatic Proxy configuration URL

Tags: c++, web-services, gsoap

How can I setup a GSOAP generated proxy client class to use an automatic HTTP proxy configuration URL?

I know I can configure the HTTP proxy address like this:

```
AnyWebServicePortBindingProxy  _client;
_client.proxy_host = "192.168.0.x";  // A valid network address.
_client.proxy_port = 8080;
_client.proxy_userid = "user";
_client.proxy_passwd = "password";
```

But what to do if I want to point to an HTTP proxy script like "http://my_proxy/proxy_script.cfg"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A proxy configuration script is actually a javascript code that returns the proxy server address based on his needs. This was meant to work with web browsers that implement the necessary logic to parse the `FindProxyForURL` response.

I don't think GSOAP is able to do the same thing without your interference.
You must check your proxy response by hand (in the beginning of the SOAP client, for example) resolve and update your gSOAP proxy configuration accordingly.